is this normal to have 22000 transcations in a testnet block of bitcoin
So I having this issue where in my local system when I hit getblock RPC method in a public node, for block number 2813986, I get around 22000 transactions in it, But when I check on blockstream.info/testnet it seems like it has only 300 transactions, So not sure which one is the correct one? any help is highly appreciated.

What is the block's hash (in getblock RPC output)?

well I don't have a block hash for that now, but here is this block 2814499
and here is the hash: 000000000000000a80ec98597306b112091422294544853e92202f8cef5ec48d
and in my local, it has 20319 transactions. wondering if this is correct or if there is some issue with it.
